# Alternative to try_files inside location

Tags: php, nginx

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name dummy;

    error_log /var/logs/error.log;
    access_log /var/logs/access.log;

    send_timeout 120s;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9080;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

        # I want to serve a php application in /var/www/cmsfiles
        # when the user visits http://localhost/cms/

    location /cms {

       root /var/www/cmsfiles;
       index index.php;

       error_log /var/logs/cms/errors.log;
       access_log /var/logs/cms/access.log;

       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_send_timeout 120s;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 500s;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

       error_page 404 index.php;

       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock; 
    }


}
```

I may need a simple change here, but I've tried for very long and nothing seems to work.

Basically what I want is `try_files` but also want to inherit the location `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `root` with `alias`, so that it chomps `/cms`:

```
location /cms {

   alias /var/www/cmsfiles;
   ...
```

Also, you will have to split the location `/cms` in two, one for static files and one for php scripts:

```
location /cms {

   alias /var/www/cmsfiles;
   index index.php;

   access_log ...

   location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi ...
   }
}
```

Comment: It's strange but changing it to `alias` doesn't solve it, it still looks for files under `/var/www/cmsfiles/cms`

Comment: It seems that `$fastcgi_script_name` still resolves to `/cms/index.php`

Comment: Are you sure you're setting `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` to the right value?